# Unmarshal into array of structs determined at runtime in Go

Tags: go

I'm trying to dynamically create a slice of structs that I can marshal my data into, but doing it at runtime based on some unknown struct type.  I'm doing this because I want to have one common bit of code that can unmarshal anything that implements a specific interface.

e.g. (pseudo code)

```
func unmarshalMyData(myInterface MyInterface, jsonData []byte) {
   targetSlice := myInterface.EmptySlice()
   json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &targetSlice)
}
```

I've tried several different alternatives.  The one that seems the most promising is using the `reflect` package to construct the slice.  Unfortunately, after unmarshalling, the dynamically created slice has a type of `[]interface{}`.  If I print out the type of the dynamically created slice before unmarshalling it prints `[]*main.myObj`.  Can anyone explain why?  See playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/vvf1leuQeY

Is there some other way to dynamically create a slice of structs that unmarshals correctly?

I'm aware of `json.RawMessage`, but there are a few reasons I can't use it... there is no "type" field in my json.  Also, the code where I am unmarshalling has no compile time knowledge of the struct that it is unmarshalling.  It only knows that the struct implements a specific interface.

Some code that baffles me as to why dynamically created slice doesn't maintain its type after unmarshalling:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    input := `[{"myField":"one"},{"myField":"two"}]`
    myObjSlice := []*myObj{}
    fmt.Printf("Type of myObjSlice before unmarshalling %T\n", myObjSlice)
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &myObjSlice)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Type of myObjSlice after unmarshalling %T\n", myObjSlice)

    myConstructedObjSlice := reflect.MakeSlice(reflect.SliceOf(reflect.TypeOf(&myObj{})), 0, 0).Interface()
    fmt.Printf("Type of myConstructedObjSlice before unmarshalling %T\n", myConstructedObjSlice)
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &myConstructedObjSlice)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Type of myConstructedObjSlice after unmarshalling %T\n", myConstructedObjSlice)
}

type myObj struct {
    myField string
}
```

The output:

```
Type of myObjSlice before unmarshalling []*main.myObj
Type of myObjSlice after unmarshalling []*main.myObj
Type of myConstructedObjSlice before unmarshalling []*main.myObj
Type of myConstructedObjSlice after unmarshalling []interface {}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're building a `[]*myObj` using reflect, but you're then passing an `*interface{}` to `json.Unmarshal`. The json package sees the target of the pointer as the type `interface{}`, and therefore uses its default types to unmarshal into. You need to create a pointer to the slice type you create, so the call to the `Interface()` method returns the exactly type you want to unmarshal into, which is `*[]*myObj`.

```
sliceType := reflect.SliceOf(reflect.TypeOf(&myObj{}))
slicePtr := reflect.New(sliceType)

err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), slicePtr.Interface())
```

Comment: Yep, that was it.  Thanks for the help!